# How to keep Internet connection while changing between eth0 and wlan0?

Tags: networking

I have a laptop which I can put onto a docking station where it is connected to the internet via ethernet (`eth0`). Otherwise, it is connected via wireless (`wlan0`).

When I plug in the ethernet cable and disable the wireless, all programs loose internet access (except the browser since it connects every single time).

How can I let all applications have internet access independant of the physical device being used? So that connections are kept alive through the interface change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application wants to use the network it asks the OS to open a socket, which is associated with source and destination IP addresses/ports.

Wikipedia:

> An Internet socket is characterized by a unique combination of the
>   following:
>   Local socket address: Local IP address and port number
>   Remote socket address: Only for established TCP sockets. As discussed
>   in the client-server section below, this is necessary since a TCP
>   server may serve several clients concurrently. The server creates one
>   socket for each client, and these sockets share the same local socket
>   address.
>   Protocol: A transport protocol (e.g., TCP, UDP, raw IP, or
>   others). TCP port 53 and UDP port 53 are consequently different,
>   distinct sockets.

When you change your network connection usually you get a different IP address, thus the earlier opened socket becomes invalid for the new connection. You'll only achieve what you want if you find a way to keep the same IP address for both wired and wireless connections.

Comment: Okay, sounds like this cannot work like I'd like it to. But the server only sees my the IP address of the router, not the one of my computer. But I guess that the router does not realize that I am the same client, just with a different IP address?

Comment: @queueoverflow Exactly. But even if the router could recognize the IP change, the Operating System will not link the already open socket to the new IP address.

Comment: is there a possibility to keep the IP address? We currently have a plain router with DHCP which will give me a random address for each device.